# how to grep on a substring column

Tags: linux, bash, grep, substring

I'd like to be able to grep/print the filename based on the 5th substring column. Only the `.03.` files in the below example.

```
dd.20211014.15000.123.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15203.143.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15404.123.01.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15033.126.06.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15000.123.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15011.323.04.11111.txt
```

Comment: for csv-like data `awk` is a better choice

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far? what (wrong) output was generated by your code? what would be an example search and the (correct) expected output? do you just need to print the match to stdout or do you need to save for later processing? if you find multiple matches do you need to process all of the matches or just the 1st (last?) match?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the layout of the line is consistent:

```sh
grep "\.03\."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to list the files and grep:

```
ls | grep ".*03.*"
```

Or using `find`:

```
find . -name '*03*'
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments - `awk` should be the weapon of choice for this:

```
ls | awk -F. '$5=="03"'
dd.20211014.15000.123.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15203.143.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15000.123.03.11111.txt
```

If you prefer regex (in case you want to later on match `03` and `04` in one go, for instance:

```
ls | awk -F. '$5~/0[34]/'
dd.20211014.15000.123.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15203.143.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15000.123.03.11111.txt
dd.20211014.15011.323.04.11111.txt
```

Comment: Excellent! this worked. thx for the added 04 bonus.  very helpful.

Comment: @user3369123 - pleased to hear. Feel free to upvote ;0 or even accept my answer :D